# JS, firebase.auth() doesn't work in global context but works inside the functions? - firebase.Auth is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have imported all the firebase scripts I need at the bottom of my HTML

```
<body>
 ...
  <script src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>

  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script>

  <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

and inside my app.js
I'm useing `firebase.auth()` on form submit and it works fine.

```
loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = loginForm.email.value;
  const password = loginForm.password.value;

  firebase
    .auth()  -> works fine here!
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((user) => {
      console.log('signed in', user);
      loginForm.reset();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      loginForm.querySelector('.error').textContent = error.message;
    });
});
```

But the problem occurs when i try to write onAuthStateChanged in global context of app.js

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    ....
  });

 // throws an error "Uncaught TypeError: firebase.Auth is not a function"
```

funny thing is that when I `console.log(firebase)` it logs out correctly and I can see auth as well other methods like functions. By the way this applies to other firebase methods and not only `auth`.

Is this some kind of bug ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the [complete, minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the error.  We should be able to copy the code and run it for ourselves to reproduce the behavior.  You'll have to be more specific than showing a code snippet "in the global context".  Actually show us how to put this together.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. This is not specific to firebase and turns out you cannot call any function directly in a global context. I suggest you place it in the componentDidMount function.

Comment: it's not a react app

Comment: @ShreeCharan don't use words like "shit" please.  This got picked up by a system that checks for abusive language.

Comment: Try putting it inside window.onload=(event)=>{ //code } ? might work